# Making CURDATE() recognize current_time()

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make this query pull a list of users 30 days from today that have a birthday.  This query works as per below in WordPress, but excludes those who have birthdays as today.  I believe the `CURDATE()` function is using the server time and not adjusting for the WordPress timezone in the Settings/General area.  Any ideas for a fix?

```
$querystr = "
SELECT * FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "usermeta
WHERE meta_key='bday_unix'
AND DATE_ADD( 
    from_unixtime(meta_value), INTERVAL YEAR( CURDATE() ) 
    - YEAR( from_unixtime( meta_value ) ) YEAR 
)
BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY )";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$current_time = current_time('mysql');

$querystr = "
SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}usermeta
WHERE meta_key='bday_unix'
AND DATE_ADD( 
    from_unixtime(meta_value), INTERVAL YEAR( '{$current_time}' ) 
    - YEAR( from_unixtime( meta_value ) ) YEAR 
)
BETWEEN '{$current_time}' AND DATE_ADD( '{$current_time}', INTERVAL 30 DAY )";
```

Should work, I think.

Comment: Right on... excellent, I'll test shortly but that should work indeed. :) I really appreciate this.